# Split string with regex delimiter in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
txt='agadsfa_(2asdf_sdfsaf)asfsadf[adsf_klnalfk;jn234kmafs)adfs,nlnawr23'
```

This is the delimiter:

```
delimiters = " \t,;.?!-:@[](){}_*/"
```

As output, I want this list of values:

```
"agadsfa","2asdf","sdfsaf","asfsadf","adsf","klnalfk","jn234kmafs","adfs","nlnawr23"
```

I tried using regex:

```
re.split(delimiters,txt)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
re.error: unterminated character set at position 10
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Is your actual input you want to capture always letters/numbers A-Z a-z 0-9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is incorrect. And from the comments, you've added the requirement that the `delimiters` string is not to be touched.

What we need to do then, is to process the input string and convert it into a proper regex that can be used by `split()`. Here's how:

```
# need to enclose regex in [], we want to split on any of
# the chars; also some of the chars need to be escaped    
delimiters = ' \t,;.?!-:@[](){}_*/'
regex = delimiters.replace(']', '\]').replace('-', '\-')
regex = r'[{}]+'.format(regex)
```

The result is as expected:

```
txt = 'agadsfa_(2asdf_sdfsaf)asfsadf[adsf_klnalfk;jn234kmafs)adfs,nlnawr23'
re.split(regex, txt)
=> ['agadsfa', '2asdf', 'sdfsaf', 'asfsadf', 'adsf', 'klnalfk', 'jn234kmafs', 'adfs', 'nlnawr23']
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, but i can't touch the delimiter string, that is determined by client, i have to give them one function where the function will separate the input string with the provided delimiter.

Comment: @avinashse you have no option, I'm afraid - the delimiter string as provided is simply not a valid regular expression for using it in `split()`. What you could do is take the delimiter string, escape the special characters and enclose the whole thing inside `[...]+`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your delimiters using `|`:

```
delimiters = r' |\t|,|;|\.|\?|!|-|:|@|\[|\]|\(|\)|\{|\}|_|\*|/'
# then use this to eliminate empty strings if you have two delimiters next to each other
print([w for w in re.split(delimiters,txt) if w])   
# or list(filter(lambda a: a, re.split(delimiters,txt)))
```

result is:

```
['agadsfa', '2asdf', 'sdfsaf', 'asfsadf', 'adsf', 'klnalfk', 'jn234kmafs', 'adfs', 'nlnawr23']
```

Comment: No need to use | here, that's what character classes [] are for. See my answer for a more concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import re

txt = "agadsfa_(2asdf_sdfsaf)asfs?adf[adsf_klna!lfk;jn234kmafs)adfs, nlnawr*23"

line = re.sub(
           r"[ \t,;\.?!\-:@\[\](){}_*/]+", 
           r",", 
           txt
       )

print(line.split(","))
```

Comment: The excessive backslashing looks like you don't really know which characters are special within a character class.

Comment: only the special chars inside char class need escaped

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 code

```
import re

txt="agadsfa_(2asdf_sdfsaf)asfsadf[adsf_klnalfk;jn234kmafs)adfs,nlnawr23"

delimiters = "_|;|,|\)|\(|\[|\]"

list(filter(None, re.split(delimiters, txt)))
```

Output

```
['agadsfa', '2asdf', 'sdfsaf', 'asfsadf', 'adsf', 'klnalfk', 'jn234kmafs', 'adfs', 'nlnawr23']
```

Separate your symbols by | and use pythons list filter function to avoid empty strings

Comment: No need to use `|` here, that's what character classes `[ ]` are for. And a properly built regex makes unnecessary the `filter` part. See my answer for a more concise solution.